# Why does macro generated formula throw err:508 but works fine manually?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Having trouble with calculating a macro generated cell formula.

The macro statement is

```
Worksheets(WorkSheet_Name).Cells(RowN, 12).Value = "=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(DATEVALUE(""1/1/2000""),$A:$A,-1),COLUMN($I$1),1,1),TRUE()):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(DATEVALUE(""" & End_Date & """),$A:$A,0),COLUMN($I$1),1,1),TRUE()))"
```

The resulting cell formula throwing Err:508 is

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(DATEVALUE("1/1/2000"),$A:$A,-1),COLUMN($I$1),1,1),TRUE()):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(DATEVALUE("03/10/2023"),$A:$A,0),COLUMN($I$1),1,1),TRUE()))
```

Copy paste in the formula bar, then enter, calculates the cell just fine.

Though Recalcuate (F9) and Recalculate Hard (Ctrl-Shift-F9) don't calculate the cell.

Works in MSO Excel but not LO Calc.

LibreOffice Calc 5.7.1.2
Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, why are you oppressing Calc (and us) with such formulas?
Why not something like `=AVERAGEIFS(I:I;A:A;">=2000-01-01";A:A;"<"&End_Date)`?

Secondly, don't use a comma - in formulas you use in Basic, always use a semicolon regardless of your local settings, this is the international standard.

Thirdly, to enter a formula into a cell, use the `.setFormula()` method instead of `.setValue()`.

And please forget constructions like `Worksheets(WorkSheet_Name).Cells()` - it's [**done differently in this office**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/guide/read_write_values.html).